# Update the second column if first column have same value

Tags: php

I am importing CSV  and saving values in Database , then displaying in php page.

**CSV**

[image]

**php page**

[image]

**Requirement** :

now when i import the another CSV , if the value of first column [ AWB ] is same [ already exists in DB ] , than i want to update the 2nd column of CSV.

Issue :

But right now , its not importing and just skipping....

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

         $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];     

         if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
         {
            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
            $i=0;
            while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {

                $getData = array_map("utf8_encode", $getData); 

                if($i==0){$i++;continue;}


                $sql = "INSERT into do_order (tracking_id,
                order_id                    
                ) 

                   values ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $getData[0])."',
                   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $getData[1])."'                
                   )";

                  // print $sql;
                  // die(); 
                   $result=$db_handle->executeUpdate($sql);
                  // print_r($db_handle->errorInfo());

                if(!isset($result))
                {
                    echo "";        
                }
                else {
                      echo "";
                }
                $i++;
             }

             fclose($file); 
         }
    }    
echo "";
```

Comment: well, use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`, or, if you want to be fancy, use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if the AWB column is your primary key

Comment: btw, you should use prepared statements instead of this `mysqli_real_escpape_string` stuff, makes it much easier to understand your SQL, and better protects against SQL injection

Comment: @KarstenKoop thanks, i tried `UPDATE` , but it didt worked for me.....

Comment: @KarstenKoop i am using `id` column as `primary key` , not `awb`.....

Comment: put a unique key on awb, and do what @KarstenKoop says.

Comment: @Cemal  is this correct : `$sql = "UPDATE into do_order set unique_key = 'tracking_id' (tracking_id,
    order_id)`

Comment: I'm not sure about the column names, fix them for yourself. Your images say you have an `ORDERID` column, your code tells you have `order_id` and you're asking for `tracking_id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166874/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-cemal).

Comment: you need to do `ALTER TABLE` only once, not in every insert

Comment: try this( case in mysql)-                                                               INSERT INTO do_order(`tracking_id`, `order_id`)
VALUES
(
   (CASE tracking_id WHEN '37' THEN NULL ELSE tracking_id END),
   (CASE order_id WHEN '4' THEN NULL ELSE order_id END)
);

Comment: @Cemal i tried as you said : https://pastebin.com/1JnsRch0 , but it didt worked for me....

Comment: @vickeycolors: you can use the same way for update as well just modify the query

Comment: @vickeycolors do you even sql bro? `ALTER TABLE` must be run without php, do not include it in the php side, leave the INSERT in the beginning of your query. just execute it from phpadmin or sthg on `do_order` table. See the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this.

You can check for the existence of `awb` (tracking id) by `SELECT * FROM do_order WHERE tracking_id='puthereyourtrackingvaluefromcvs'` and if the number of rows > 0 for it, then do `UPDATE do_order SET order_id = 'PutYourNewOrderIdFromCvs' WHERE tracking_id='puthereyourtrackingvaluefromcvs'`

Or you can change your table's schema once by executing

```
ALTER TABLE do_order ADD UNIQUE (`tracking_id`);
```

then in every insert

```
$sql = "INSERT into do_order (tracking_id,order_id) values 
      ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $getData[0])."','".
          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $getData[1])."') 
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE order_id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $getData[1])."'";
```

**Important Note** Do not use mysqli* and even if you have to, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: thanks, i tried `ALTER TABLE do_order ADD UNIQUE (`tracking_id`);`

Comment: than i used this : https://pastebin.com/zHCH6AM7 please check and tell me

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY SET order_id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $getData[1])."'";`   means it will allow duplicate orders ?

Comment: means if awb is same , than it will update order_id column ?

Comment: but its not working for me..... its not updating new value in order_id column.....

Comment: is awb = tracking id?